# Unable to execute cron.php via SSH nor CRONTAB

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

I recently hosted my website using Magento, upon setting up my cron.php i get the following output :

```
/home/xxx/webapps/abc/cron.php: line 1: ?php
: No such file or directory
/home/xxx/webapps/abc/cron.php: line 2: /**
: No such file or directory
/home/xxx/webapps/abc/cron.php: line 3: bin: command not found
/home/xxx/webapps/abc/cron.php: line 4: $'*\r': command not found
/home/xxx/webapps/abc/cron.php: line 5: bin: command not found
/home/xxx/webapps/abc/cron.php: line 6: $'*\r': command not found
/home/xxx/webapps/abc/cron.php: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/xxx/webapps/abc/cron.php: line 7: ` * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
```

'

I host this on Webfaction, and it appears that this error only happen on Webfaction. My other website (using the same Magento version) which is hosted on another service runs just fine.

Even after i removed the following lines on cron.php, it still does not work:

```
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
```

I've also tried to put "shebang" just before the php opening tag like so:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
```

And get this result:

```
/usr/local/bin/php^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

[image: Location of PHP]

This is what happen when i run `php cron.php`

[image]

I suspect that there might be something wrong with the encoding. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Please check the path to php using `whereis php`

Comment: @rafal-kos please see my edit.

Comment: btw whereis php return this : php: /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/php

Comment: And how you are calling this cron file? You are trying to run cron.sh or cron.php?

Comment: @rafal-kos cron.sh will eventually call cron.php, since calling php cron.php is not working cron.sh is also not working.

Comment: but when you run `php cron.php` you still have an error?

Comment: @rafal-kos it does not show anything, please see my edit

Comment: but this script ends and new line is beign displayed or it is not finishing?

Comment: Nothing appears/comes up as if it is went to infinite loop

Comment: And can you check db  processes? Maybe some long cron job is running then?

Comment: What about if you run /usr/local/bin/php -v? Also what about 'whereis php-cli'?

Answer (score 0):

How often are you trying to run the script?

Try something like this:

*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/mour/cron.sh

That should execute the cron.sh script every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

After new security patch **`cron.php`** does not work directly for that you have to add **`cron.sh`** file in your crontab that actually triggers **`cron.php`** different way and your all cron related task works

for adding **`cron.sh`** in your crontab you can use below syntax

> `*/5 * * * * /bin/sh magento_base_dir/cron.sh`

Please try and let me know